# Assigning contents of file to an object?

Tags: php, json, serialization

I currently have external JSON files that PHP uses to set up a request's validations and filters. This makes it easy to assign the contents of a file as an object to a variable.

```
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents($filepath));
```

I am wondering if there might be another way to do this that would not involve parsing JSON? I would like to still be able to assign the contents of a file to a variable runtime, but is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Hardly. If you want to use JSON in PHP, you need to parse it. No way around it

Comment: JSON is JSON, why would like want to use JSON without using JSON functions?

Comment: @Pekka I know, but perhaps there is a way to accomplish the same thing without using JSON at all.

Comment: So, you want just to save your data and load it later?

Comment: @dqhendricks well, you could have PHP files instead? That define arrays or classes? That's the only other method that comes to mind

Comment: An option to JSON would be PHP [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize)

Comment: @Lekensteyn to clarify, using JSON is not a requirement.

Comment: @bfavaretto I imagine that takes a similar amount of time as parsing JSON.

Comment: @Pekka but how could I assign the contents of the file to a variable runtime? as far as I could tell, each file would have to have a named variable or class within the file.

Comment: Yes, it may even be slower. I'd go with Pekka's suggestion then.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Includes can return a value with the `return` statement, e.g. `$var = include($file);`.

Comment: @hakre wow that's pretty cool. return statement in the global space of an included file allows assignment using a files contents. put this in a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds complicated... I would suggest having a collection of php class files that are included on call using `require_once();`

It does depend on what is stored in these files though.

There is another method in php called `parse_ini_file();` [[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)] but its only good for key-value pairs.

Comment: It's said that `parse_ini_file` is pretty fast.

Comment: unfortunately parse ini will not work as there is more to the structure of the data than key-value pairs.

Comment: I'd use included php class files and if you are worried about performance then use something like memcache - http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: @dqhendricks it might be possible to have a generic php class that has all of the validation requirements in it and its specific process is defined by the KVP's that you have in an INI file? From memory the parse ini file has sections and key value pairs but thats the limit of its granularity.

Comment: after further looking into it, sections feature allowed me to create a data structure I can use out of an ini file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit3:** To assign something non-static to a variable from a file, you can make use of the `return` statement inside the file and then include the file to assign it to a variable:

```
$var = include($file);
```

`$file` must be a file with correct PHP syntax (see [`include`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/include) and the `return` statement. Then you're ready to go.

Include therefore is pretty similar to `eval` on the language level, so take care.

---

There is another way, like JSON is serialization, there is [`serialize`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/unserialize) as well in PHP.

```
$object = unserialize(file_get_contents($filepath));

file_put_contents($filepath, serialize($object));
```

It's said, that this is slower than with `json_encode` / `json_decode` (I have not measured it).

The benefit with it is, that there is better support for concrete PHP object instances, it just better integrates with the language (no wonder, as it's core PHP).

**Edit:** As commented, you want to manually edit the files. PHP serialized data (by default) is not very human read/edit friendly, so you might look for some serialization into XML: [`XML_Serializer` <sup>**PEAR Package**</sup>](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/redirected). Another [XML Serializer is available in Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/1467bdb86837e132891dd1b5605248a736cca5fe/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer) and it supports other formats, too (like JSON).

The other alternative is to switch the PHP serializer to [WDDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDDX) (ships with core PHP), which actually is XML.

**Edit2:** There is something similar to JSON for PHP: `eval` and `var_export`. But beware this is somewhat dirty (or better say evil) and the concrete class needs to support this (if using objects), too:

```
$var = array('prop' => 'some value');

ob_start();
var_export($var);
$buffer = ob_get_clean();

# $buffer now contains something that can be saved,
# to load it again:

$var = eval('return '.$buffer.';');

var_dump($var);
```

[Sandbox](http://codepad.org/STJs9hdd)

Comment: slower, and then i have to save it from within php to serialize. i would like to be able to edit the file by hand.

Comment: You can edit serialized data by hand, you just might need a hex editor and know what you do. Well bad joke. You might be looking for XML serialization, that exists, will add a link to the answer.